# Bash syntax string insertion

Tags: bash

I have a command which I want to have as a function in my .bashrc.

From the commandline

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext {} - | grep --with-filename --label={} --color "string of words" ' \;
```

Will find "string of words" in any pdf in the current directory.

Despite the best part of an hour, I seriously can't get "string of words" to work as a string variable - i.e.

```
eg="string of words"

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext {} - | grep --with-filename --label={} --color $eg ' \;
```

Which obviously won't work, but I have tried all kinds of combinations of `"/'/\` with `echo` hacks, array expansions, but no luck. I'm sure its possible, and I'm sure its easy, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You might be having fun writing this, but have you considered just installing [pdfgrep](https://gitorious.org/pdfgrep)?

Answer (score 0):

Things like variable expansion only work inside of double quotes, not single quotes. Have you tried using double quotes on that sring?

Like so:

```
find . -name "*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext {} - | grep --with-filename --label={} --color $eg " \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the single quotes `'` around the `pdftotext` command.  The single quotes will prevent any variable expansion in the string which they occur.  You may have more luck with double quotes `"`.

```
eg="string of words"

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c "pdftotext {} - | grep --with-filename --label={} --color $eg " \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest to do:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec \
  sh -c 'pdftotext $0 - | grep --with-filename --label=$0 --color "$1"' {} "$eg" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate the logic just a bit differently than what you've done:

```
eg="string of words"
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c "pdftotext {} - | \
   grep -H --label={} --color '$eg'" \;
```

i.e., by making the shell process outer quote delimiter `"`, the shell variable expansion works, and delimiting the search variable with `'` preserves it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Write a small shell script `mypdfgrep` and call that from `find`:

```
#/bin/bash

pdftotext "$1" - | grep --with-filename --label "$1" --color "$2"
```

Then run

```
$ chmod +x mypdfgrep
$ find . -name '*.pdf' -execdir /full/path/to/mypdfgrep '{}' "string of words" \;
```